# PickerView hour and show in a Label

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipickerview

I want to know how i create a picker view Hour, and then what i selectioned appear in a label....then put this hour in a condition (IF).??

can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please detail what you have already tried, and any errors you may have received. Thx

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In .h file define these variables:

```
UIPickerView       *picker;
NSArray            *HOURS_24;
UILabel            *hourLabel;
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
HOURS_24=[[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects: @" 8:00", @" 9:00", @" 10:00", @" 11:00",
          @" 12:00", @" 13:00", @" 14:00", @" 15:00", @" 16:00", @" 17:00", @" 18:00", nil];

//Add picker in XIB or add it using code like below.
picker=[[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(100,100,100,100)];
picker.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:picker];

hourLabel=[[UILable alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake: (20,100,50,20)];
[self.view addSubview:hourLabel];
hourLabel.text=@"This is hour label";
```

Add these functions

```
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
  (UIPickerView *)pickerView
 {
    return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
  numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
    return [HOURS_24 count];
 }
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
    return [HOURS_24 objectAtIndex:row];
 }
```

Implementing the delegate:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{  
  hourLabel.text=[HOURS_24 objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go through this sample project-------  http://www.dosomethinghere.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/DatePickerExample.zip

for check you could use .text of the label e.g. if(date label.text==.......)
hope this helps...